# CSS Div Table Position Issues

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is, if you head to you will see in the table that 4,9,10 are slightly tilted towards left which I have no clue why? Can you please check and suggest what I can do to fix this.

I'm using table format because I want everything to be vertically aligned and have no other alternative (unless someone else comes up with any). I am also using bootstrap.

Comment: can you please show the link and code

Comment: I did, but for some reason I can directly link to the website, it's website builders [dot] org

Comment: Website doesn't load. Also, with StackOverflow, we prefer to have code posted for posterity and historical reference. Once you tweak your site, this question will be useless to future readers.

Comment: Actually I don't know exactly what to copy here since it's a big css code pile, maybe I can copy parts of style.css? There was a mistake with the link, it's fixed now.

Comment: main div container (if any) + output of structure one (maybe 2 if different styles) table(s) + css related part should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a width to your "letstest" class:

```
.letstest {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If there's no width set, then the table will take up just enough space for the content.  Some of the images or text could alter this.  Hope that helps.